# i'm not getting the right output, when using assignment operator

Tags: python-3.x

Given an integer, , perform the following conditional actions:      If is odd, print Weird     If is even and in the inclusive range of to , print Not Weird     If is even and in the inclusive range of to , print Weird     If is even and greater than , print Not Weird

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input("Enter a number:"))

    if n % 2 != 0:
        print("Weird")

    elif n % 2 == 0:
        for n in range(2,5):
            print("Not Weird")

    elif n % 2 == 0:
        for n in range(6,20):
            print("Weird")

    elif n% 2 == 0 && (n > 20):

            print("Not Weird")
```

Answer (score 0):

[`for`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) is a loop, and [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) is a generator (actually an [immutable sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range)), it does not do what you think it is doing. You need to look at more `if` and `elif` statements, example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input("Enter a number:"))

    if n % 2 != 0:
        print("Weird")
    else:
        if 2 <= n <= 5:
            print("Not Weird")
        elif 6 <= n <= 20:
            print("Weird")
        elif n > 20:
            print("Not Weird")
        else:
            print("n = 0 or even-and-negative")
```

Comment: THis still return an error for me..